# Pre-loading multiple videos on a page

Tags: android, performance

Do apps like Vine or Instagram pre-load videos so that they play quickly?

I want to show about 5 video thumbnails on the screen at a time, which would play full screen in a fragment when clicked.

I'm wondering if pre-loading 5 videos would be a bad idea or inefficient?

These videos will be roughly 5-10 seconds in length.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: That's pretty subjective, but consider that this might only be a good idea if you're on WiFi. Otherwise you're using up a lot of bandwidth that may be wasted if the user never views the video. Conversely if you can determine that the user is fairly likely to view all the videos it might be worth it. Again, subjective.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for the input! Definitely needs to be considered.